# $M\simeq X\oplus Y$ and $M/X \simeq Y$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am trying to prove that if $M,X,Y$ are modules over a ring $D$, then $M\simeq X\oplus Y$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $M/X \simeq Y$

"$\Longrightarrow$''
I consider the map $f_1:x\in X \rightarrow (x,0)\in X\oplus Y$ and $f_2:(x,y)\in X\oplus Y \rightarrow y \in Y$ and using $M/X \simeq (X\oplus Y)/X \simeq (X\oplus Y)/\text{Ker}(f_2) \simeq \text{Im}(f_2)=Y$

However I can not prove it the other way.

Comment: Maybe you need to be more specific about $X$ and $Y$? Even in the direction you've shown you're a little loose. In general the other direction doesn't have to be true: look at the quotient of $2\mathbf{Z} \subset \mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: You can't because it's false: take M= **Z**  X=n**Z**, Y= **Z**/n**Z**. It would imply **Z** has torsion elements.

Comment: @user26857 Can I ask you about a condition for freeness over a local reduced ring [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19692/atiyah-macdonald-discussion)? (I am just repurposing the room)

Comment: For $M/X$ to be well-defined, you need to say that $X$ is a submodule of $M$. The $\Leftarrow$ direction is wrong: e.g., take $D = M = \mathbb{Z}$, $X = 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $Y = M/X$. Then the image $i$, say, of 1 in $Y$ satisfies $i + i = 0$, but no element of $M$ does, so $M$ cannot be isomorphic to $X \oplus Y$.

Comment: @user26857 It's rather a loose question about a theorem in Bourbaki's CA that a module is free if the dimension of $M$ over each minimal prime is the same as that of $M$ over its residue field, i.e. how can it be interpreted in more geometrical terms say.